# Convert rdd.PipelinedRDD into a sql.dataframe.DataFrame without collect() method

Tags: python, pyspark, out-of-memory

I would like to convert an rdd.PipelinedRDD into an sql.dataframe.DataFrame with PySpark.
The PipelinedRDD looks as follows:

```
[(1.0, '#1John #2Doe'),
 (2.0, '#1Adam #2Smith'),
 (3.0, '#1Benjamin #2Miller')]
```

The DataFrame should then look something like:

```
[Row(_1=1, _2='#1John #2Doe'),
 Row(_1=2, _2='#1Adam #2Smith'),
 Row(_1=3, _2='#1Benjamin #2Miller')]
```

I managed to do this with the following code:

```
df = sc.parallelize(rdd.collect()).map(lambda x: [int(x[0]), x[1]]).toDF()
```

However, when using this code for a large dataset I get an OutOfMemoryError. I think the problem is the collect() method. Is there a way to do this more efficiently?

Comment: No unfortunately not... I already tried these solutions, but they didn't work for me.

Comment: Doesn't this work? `spark.createDataFrame(rdd, "_1 float, _2 string")`

Comment: No, this throws the following error: ```TypeError: field _1: LongType can not accept object 1.0 in type <class 'numpy.float64'>```

Comment: I found my mistake! I needed to convert the datatype to FloatType(). Thank you so much - this really helped a lot!!